# Azure Graph API - Check if IUser is a room or resource

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the [ActiveDirectory GraphClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) library by Microsoft to access an Azure AD.

In my ***IActiveDirectoryClient* object** I can access all users by using the collection in ***Users* property**.

By using the ***ExecuteAsync()* method** I can load all users, rooms and recources.

```
void async Task<List<IUser>> GetRooms(IActiveDirectoryClient client)
{
    var rooms = new List<IUser>();

    var pagedUsers = await client.Users.ExecuteAsync();
    while (pagedUsers != null &&
           pagedUsers.CurrentPage != null)
    {
        // enumerate IUser objects
        foreach (IUser u in pagedUsers.CurrentPage)
        {
            //TODO: HOW-TO CHECK IF ROOM
        }

        /* load next page */
    }

    return rooms;
}
```

**My problem is:**

I'd like to get to know from an ***IUser*** object if it is a room or resource but I do not know where to look.

Comment: What is your problem ? I don't think there is room object in the Azure AD. In Exchange you have this kind of objects but in the AD. At least yu've create custom properties ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write what my problem is ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such object in the Azure AD. But you can extend the Azure AD User object to create custom properties :

- [Extend Azure Active Directory Schema using Graph API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/03/05/extend-azure-active-directory-schema-using-graph-api-preview/)

Room mailbox is an object related to [Exchange and Exchange online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj215781(v=exchg.160).aspx).